# How to change a single light switch to a light switch/receptical combo?

Tags: electrical

I have a light switch downstairs which is a remote switch for a ceiling fixture upstairs, the light switch downstairs works with a light switch upstairs that for the same ceiling fixture.

I want to remove the light switch that's downstairs and replace it with a combination light switch/receptacle.  At the downstairs location there are three wires - I have already tried (without success) to hook up the combo
switch/receptacle - but when I plug a vacuum into the receptacle, turning on the vacuum - turns on the ceiling fixture, but not the vacuum.  I know there is power in one of the 3 wires, I have tried the 3 wires on each of the terminals of the combo.

I have done switch changes before. So I have extremely puzzeled on why it's not working that way it's meant to.

Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72811/discussion-on-question-by-sh-queens-how-to-change-a-single-light-switch-to-a-lig).

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/is-there-some-kind-of-adapter-for-an-old-ceiling-box