# How to install a universal cross bar?

Tags: electrical

I have an extremely old (over 60 years) wall box which has a center bolt/nipple for mounting a light fixture.  I want to install a universal cross bar that has a center hole (to go over the center bolt/nipple). There are no screw holes in any corner or side of the box, what can I attache/mount the universal cross bar to?

Comment: please post a picture

Comment: Here is a link to another posting with the same type of problem - mine is with a wall box and the box has no screw holes in corners or sides  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/is-there-some-kind-of-adapter-for-an-old-ceiling-box